# How to transfer a Uri image from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap, uri

In my app I need to transfer a Uri image from my first Activity to another. I know how to send a Bitmap through an intent. I'm a bigginer programmer so I don't know what would be better to do: transfer the Uri with an intent or change the Uri to a Bitmap then send that?

Comment: if it is only one process just add a public static field to your activity class and assign the Uri to it before you execute the intent.

Comment: Can you please make an answer with sample code. I'll be happy to accept it if it works.

Comment: Don't send an entire bitmap via intent; send the uri itself as an extra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use with putExtra to send the Uri Path:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent .setClass(ThisActivity.this,  NewActivity.class);
            intent .putExtra("KEY", Uri);
            startActivity(intent );
```

In the newActivity OnCreate method:

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("KEY")) {
        Uri= extras.getString("KEY");
    }
```

Use those func:
Uri to String:

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
stringUri = uri.toString();
```

String to Uri:

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
```

Comment: How do I access the Uri in the second Activity?

Comment: I placed the buttom code in the second Activity in a Uri and I got an error that I should place it in a String

Comment: Thank you very much! In general the code works but the transition in the way I want to use it doesn't. I want to take a photo from the gallery then put it over a camera preview on a different Activity. The app crashes when I transfer to the camera preview page and I really don't know why... I attached links to the activity for picking a photo fron the gallery and the camera priview activity, please help me if you can. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y0yG_4vLrLzRww3C5_fNasUHQwAoKazIS6jEKC-sqGE/pub https://docs.google.com/document/d/17620g9p2wZ4qEIrYWhO3ilOkgKn2rm8p68FcDdu6R7Q/pub

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the error you are getting, in the code given by Miki franko, replace the line :

```
Uri= extras.getString("KEY");
```

with :

```
uri= Uri.parse(extras.getString("KEY"));
```

This is just to make the code work as I think you didn't understand what Miki tried to explain through the code.
Keep us posted if you get it resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //First Activity to get a Uri
        String uri_Str = Uri.toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent .putExtra("uri_Str", uri_Str);
        startActivity(intent);


       //Second Activity get a Uri path
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
        String uri_Str= b.getString("uri_Str");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uri_Str);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First Activity

   ```
    Uri uri = data.getData();
           Intent intent=new Intent(Firstclass.class,secondclass.class);
           intent.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString());
           startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Second class

   ```
   Imageview iv_photo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
   iv_photo.setImageURI(myUri);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your first class, you can pass the image uri like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("your_key", imageUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the second or receiver activity, you can access the image uri this way:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("your_key"));
}
```